# AWS openshift Multus CNI

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-pod, cni

I was going through the recent addition of the Multus network plugin to Openshift which help pod to have multiple network interfaces. So my question if we install openshift on AWS with the Multus plugin, Is this going to reduce the number of pods one instance if we use multiple network interfaces in pods. As the number of pod running on the instance depends on attached eni and that depends on the instance type

Answer (score 0):

The usage of additional networks is not to reduce number of pods its mainly for situations where network isolation is needed, including data plane and control plane separation. Isolating network traffic is useful for the following performance and security reasons:

**Performance**

You can send traffic on two different planes in order to manage how much traffic is along each plane.

**Security**

You can send sensitive traffic onto a network plane that is managed specifically for security considerations, and you can separate private data that must not be shared between tenants or customers

Comment: Thanks, Arghya but the problem in AWS is every instance has limited ENI so the number of IP is also limited. The maximum number of pods that can be scheduled on each worker node using the following formula..maxPods = (number of interfaces - 1) * (max IPv4 address per interface - 1) + 2
For example, the m5.large instance type Inserting the values into the formula, the instance can support a maximum of 20 pods, as shown in the following calculation.
maxPods = (3 - 1) * (10 - 1) + 2 = 20. So if we attach more network interface to the same pod the number of pods also decreases, right?